# Python Selenium and PhantomJS dont open tweet form modal

Tags: python, selenium, twitter, phantomjs

I use selenium,phantomjs for send tweet on python. It works successfully when set browser Firefox and Chrome. But If I set browser PhantomJS something is going wrong. I saved screenshoot and the cause of problem that PhantomJS doesnt open global tweet modal so it couldnt find tweet form which is in modal.

There is no problem  when I use Firefox() instead of PhantomJS. It open modal and send tweet successfully.

The code :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import time
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.set_window_size(1024, 768)
browser.get('https://www.twitter.com')
browser.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds

#login
element = browser.find_element_by_id("signin-email")
element.clear()
element.send_keys("username")

element = browser.find_element_by_id("signin-password")
element.clear()
element.send_keys("password")

element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']")
element. click()

#open global tweet modal
element = browser.find_element_by_id("global-new-tweet-button")
element.click()
browser.save_screenshot('screen.png') # save screen

# set tweet content
element = browser.find_element_by_id("tweet-box-global")
element.click() #focus tweet textarea which is in modal form
element.send_keys("twitter test with selenium")

# submi,t tweet form
form = browser.find_element_by_id("global-tweet-dialog")
element = form.find_elements_by_css_selector("button.tweet-action.tweet-btn")[0]
element.click()

browser.quit()
```

I also tried to open modal with javascript but it didnt work

```
browser.execute_script("document.getElementById('global-new-tweet-button').click()")
```

Comment: Try explicit waiting for the element to load before locating it, it may be loading dynamically. Here are the docs for it http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida I already set "browser.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds" . I waits 10 seconds until find the element. It is equal with you said

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida I also tried  element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "global-new-tweet-button"))
    ) but the problem still continue